# Is there a limit which is hard to compute without L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know that for limits having $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ form, L'Hôpital's rule
is a great tool. But usually these problems can be solved without using it like using Taylor series, etc.
So I wanted to ask if there is any limit which can be computed extremely easily with L'Hôpital's rule but relatively takes a lot of steps and some tricks/observations if you try to do without it.

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule yields a quick proof of the asymptotics $\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log t}  \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$ ($x\to+\infty$). You can also do it using integration by parts and estimating the remainder but that takes more time.

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is also used to evaluate limits of the form $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are high degree polynomial (where factorisation is quite tough). In this case, L'Hôpital's rule can be used. *Note that the rule is applicable only for $0/0$ and $∞/∞$ forms.*

Comment: Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Examples